# How do I check if the secret key polynomial of the ATV-FHE (NTRU based) scheme is invertible?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ntru

I want to implement the ATV-FHE scheme as described here https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/039.pdf. To generate the secret key polynomial I compute f = 2*u + 1 , with scheme parameters chosen such that this polynomial is invertible with high probability.

If I want to compute the public key I should compute it as indicated in section 2 :

> $h(i) = 2g(i)*[ ( f(i) )^{(-1)} ]$

or should I sample the public key as indicated in section 3 Parameter selection in NTRU_FHE :

> Recall that for the NTRU-FHE scheme, the public key is of the form $h = 2gf^{(-1)}$  where $g$; $f$ chosen from
>   a Gaussian distribution $D$ where $f$ is kept secret. The DSPR problem is to distinguish polynomials
>   of the form $h = 2gf^{(-1)}$  from samples $h_0$ picked uniformly at random from the ring $Rq$. If the DSPR
>   problem is hard, we can replace $h = 2gf^{(-1)}$ by some uniformly sampled $h_0$.

The bad part for the second option (described in section 3) is that parameter selection is very difficult to be made as noted here

> The impact of the new parameter settings to the security level is largely unknown
>   and requires careful research. However, even if we assume that the DSPR problem is hard for typical NTRU-FHE parameter selection, concrete parameters are still hard to chose. The RLWE problem is still relatively new and lacks thorough security analysis.$h_0$.

I have found an alternative so far: to generate a random polynomial and to verify if this polynomial is the invers of the secret key polynomial. Here is an example : https://github.com/tlepoint/homomorphic-simon/blob/master/YASHE/YASHEKey.cpp, in constructor YASHEKey::YASHEKey there is a portion of code

```
if(sigmakey == 1)
{
    // Sample g, f1 with coefficients in {-1,0,1} 
    fmpz_mod_polyxx g(q);

    fmpz_mod_polyxx f1(q);

    binaryGen(g, ell-1);

    do
    {
        binaryGen(f1, ell-1);
        *f = t*f1+one;
        finv = (*f).invmod(*phi);
    } 
    while (((*f)*finv)%(*phi) != one);

    *h = (t*g*finv)%(*phi);
}
```

Comment: This is a nontrivial question for any cryptosystem like NTRU, unfortunately. It involves lots of pretty complex math. Here's a technical report on the subject that may help you: https://www.securityinnovation.com/uploads/Crypto/NTRUTech009.pdf

Comment: Your 2nd "option" to select the secret key is not an option at all. It is part of the security proof, in which one assumption "$h=2gf^{(-1)}$ with $f, g$ Gaussian and $f$ secret" is replace by another assumption "$h'$ is uniformly sampled". Distinguishing $h$ from $h'$ is the DSPR-problem, and it's assumed to be hard.